# Why is setState being called synchronously?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using setState inside an animation frame, expecting it to be queued like it normally does. But instead it runs immediately.

What's worse, if there are any pending effects then those are *also* resolved, meaning my effect cleanup is called while I'm still inside of animation frame, so I request a next animation frame that never gets cleaned up.

Notice how the timer is speeding up in this example:

```js
let handling = false
let accum = 0

function MyComponent() {
    const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        let frame
        let time = undefined
        function handle(t) {
          handling = true
          frame = undefined
          if (time != null) {
            // this is for the sake of demonstration, so we don't get throttled by react's performance
            accum += t - time
            setState(Math.floor(accum / 1000))
          }
          time = t
          frame = window.requestAnimationFrame(handle)
          handling = false
        }
        if (handling) console.log('oh no!')
        frame = window.requestAnimationFrame(handle)
        return () => window.cancelAnimationFrame(frame)
    })

    React.useEffect(() => {
      window.setInterval(() => {
        setState(x => x + 0.0001)
      }, 111)
    }, [])
    
    return <div>{Math.round(state)}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.querySelector('.root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div class="root"></div>
```

I recognize I could change it to something like this to ensure I don't request a new frame when I shouldn't, but it feels like this clunky code should be avoided?

```js
let frame
let time = undefined
let effectIsOver = false
function handle(t) {
  handling = true
  frame = undefined
  if (time != null) {
    setState(s => s + t - time)
  }
  time = t
  if (!effectIsOver) frame = window.requestAnimationFrame(handle)
  handling = false
}
frame = window.requestAnimationFrame(handle)
return () => {
  window.cancelAnimationFrame(frame)
  effectIsOver = true
}
```

Comment: `useEffect` needs a second param or otherwise, it'll get called _each_ time component re-renders.

Comment: I didn't include it because it's an example and I'm not optimizing it for performance. Running an effect multiple times is normal, because it has a cleanup function. But the cleanup doesn't work as expected here, because it's called *while the effect is already running*.

Comment: It's not just for optimization. It gets called after each `setState` call, which means it accumulates drastically and eventually will break your computer. And I believe the "speeding up" is because of it.

Comment: That's what the cleanup function is for...

Comment: No. Cleanup function gets called when the component unmounts.

Comment: No, it gets called before the effect is replaced by a new instance of the same effect. Please read the documentation.